# In webproject .java file not compiled

Tags: java, jsp, compiler-construction

I am working with ellipse Galileo with Tomcat 6 configured but while i am changing any code to my .java file and trying to use these modified file (i.e.  method added newly in that .java file) my console is showing that method is undefined.

I am not able to figure why its happening?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally turned off automatic builds? See if Project->Build automatically is checked or not.

Comment: What's wrong with if I need to press `Save` to my files compile?

Comment: build is successful but still not deployed properly

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 issues

1)Either your changed java files are not getting complied properly
2)While publishing the changes via Eclipse, new class files are not getting deployed to the tomcat directory.
you can manually try to copy paste the classes file in to the tomcat directory to make it work.

In RAD, we use J2ee module dependency option to configure which java projects we need to deploy as jar at the deploy time. similarly, eclipse should have that option too.